# I want a function to run for forever in node js(Express js) without requesting any route

Tags: node.js, express

1.I want this function to run after 50second for forever in Node js(Express js). It is running in local host when I using nodemon
index.js but in the heroku it is not running

2.Whether function runs all the time

3.Error running in heroku free server but running on local host.

```
const moment = require('moment');
let now = moment().format('L');
console.log("current date changes everyday", now)
let startdate = moment().subtract(1, "days").format('L');
let enddate = moment().add(4, "days").format('L');
console.log("start date", startdate)
console.log("end date", enddate);
const availableSlots = ["08.00 AM - 08.30 AM",
  "08.30 AM - 09.00 AM",
  "09.00 AM - 9.30 AM",
  "09.30 AM - 10.00 AM",
  "10.00 AM - 10.30 AM",
  "10.30 AM - 11.00 AM",
  "11.00 AM - 11.30 PM",
  "11.30 AM - 12.00 PM",
  "4.00 PM - 4.30 PM",
  "4.30 PM - 5.00 PM",
  "5.00 PM - 5.30 PM",
  "5.30 PM - 6.00 PM",
  "6.00 PM - 6.30 PM",
  "6.30 PM - 7.00 PM",
  "7.00 PM - 7.30 PM"]

console.log(now); //is a type string

const DynamicDate = async () => {
  // console.log("day inside function", day);
  console.log("function running");
  const hospitaldoctorsCollection = client.db(process.env.DB).collection('hospitaldoctors');
  const query = {}
  const cursor = hospitaldoctorsCollection.find(query);
  const doctors = await cursor.toArray();
  for (let i = 0; i < doctors.length; i++) {
    const doctor = doctors[i];  //will be an object
    const doctorId = doctor._id;
    let doctorAvialableSlot = doctor.availableSlots; //will be an object of an doctor object
    // console.log(doctorAvialableSlot[now])
    if (doctorAvialableSlot[startdate] !== undefined) {
      console.log(true);
      delete doctorAvialableSlot[startdate];
      // plus a date now then do another 
      doctorAvialableSlot[enddate] = availableSlots;
      const filter = { _id: ObjectId(doctorId) };
      const options = { upsert: true };
      const updateDoc = {
        $set: { availableSlots: doctorAvialableSlot }
      };
      const result = await hospitaldoctorsCollection.updateOne(filter, updateDoc, options);

    } else {
      console.log("All slot are up to date");
    }
  }
}

setInterval(DynamicDate, 50000)
```

Comment: Hi, can you paste code here instead of putting it as an image ? Thanks!

Comment: Please now check it and help me

Comment: If you're running a free or very inexpensive hosting plan, you are not going to be able to run something for a long time.  Inexpensive hosting plans are targeted at short lived http requests only.  The economics of the inexpensive hosting plan have to guarantee that you aren't continually using server resources such as CPU, disk I/O, database I/O, etc...

Comment: On heroku free server, server automatically sleeps upto 30mins of inactivtity. Do you see logs before ? Btw, you need to write npm start script in your package.json file if not writen

Comment: Yeah it's a free plan but the function is not even running for a single time brother

Comment: @ovilashMoitra I will check locally and then deploy to heroku server for checking issues